How to use class weights with DistributedSampler in Pytorch?
I have a highly imbalanced dataset that I need to train on a multi-gpu setup. On a single gpu the class imbalance could be handled by WeightedRandomSampler. Then I would pass the sampler object to the DataLoader. But in a multi-gpu setup, since I am using DistributedSampler as the sampler, I cannot pass WeightedRandomSampler the same way. How to use both in my DataLoader?
Here's my code with DistributedSampler:
train_dataset = SampleDataset(data_root=data_root, transform=train_transforms, num_classes=num_classes)
train_sampler = DistributedSampler(train_dataset, num_replicas=world_size)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset,
                              batch_size=batch_size,
                              pin_memory=True,
                              sampler=train_sampler,
                              num_workers=0)



Not really an answer, but maybe a hint: You could take a look at Meta's (aka Facebook's) JEPA project, which provides a DistributedWeightedSampler in PyTorch here.
